# Prevent showing double tooltips in same cell in AgGrid

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip, mouseevent, ag-grid

[Overlapping tooltips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uW6V.png)

We are using a custom tooltip component in Ag Grid to show a tooltip with more information for that cell. In that same cell we also have a Complete Task button, that has a bootstrap tooltip assigned to it.
When I hover over the Complete Task button, I want to stop showing the custom tooltip from that cell.
How can I stop this behavior? I've tried using stopPropagation, but that doesn't seem to work in Ag Grid.
Below a simplified version of the code.

custom-tooltip.component.ts

```
    agInit(params: ITooltipParams<any>): void {
        const value = params.value as ITaskCellValue;
        this.createdDate = this.dp.transform(value.createdAt, 'MMMM d, y');
    }
```

custom-tooltip.component.html

```
    <div data-id="task-tooltip">
        <span class="bold">Data Update Task</span>
        <span class="normal">Created: {{createdDate}}</span>
    </div>
```

custom-renderer.component.ts

```
    agInit(params: ICustomRendererParams): void {
        if (params.value != null) {
            params.colDef.tooltipField = params.colDef.field;
            params.colDef.tooltipComponent = 'customTooltipComponent';
        }
```

custom-renderer.component.html

```
    <div data-id="datatable-cell-tasks">
        <span>{{displayValue}}</span>
        <button class="btn btn-full align-self-center d-flex primaryButtonType"
            data-id="complete-task-button"
            [tooltip]="tooltip"
            container="body"
            triggers="hover"
            placement="bottom"
            [delay]="500"
            (click)="handleTaskComplete()">
        <span class="fa fa-check align-self-center btn-icon mx-1"></span>
    </div>
    <ng-template #tooltip>Complete Task</ng-template>
```